# Why is useContext returning null in a component even though its parent tag is marked as the Provider?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-context

I have been trying to get the user state to be accessible in my child react component using react-hooks and react-context for the last few hours and I can't figure it out. In several other related questions posted on this site, useContext was returning null/undefined because the component in which it was used wasn't enclosed by a tag that was marked as the Provider.

Here, I've done this, but it's still not working. When I log the value of useContext(AuthContext), it returns null, but when I log the object that's assigned to AuthContext.Provider, it shows the user data. Help would be greatly appreciated.

App.js

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, Button, View } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';

// import firebase
import firebase from './firebase.js';

console.log(firebase)
const db = firebase.database();

var isSignedIn = true;
var testing = true

import AuthNavigator from './src/navigation/AuthNavigator'

export default function App() {
  return <AuthNavigator />
}
```

AuthNavigator.js

```
import firebase from './../../firebase.js';
// import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth'
import SignInStack from './SignInStack'
import SignOutStack from './SignOutStack'
import TestScreen from './TestScreen'

export const AuthContext = createContext(null)

export default function AuthNavigator() {
    const [initializing, setInitializing] = useState(true)
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null)
  
    // Handle user state changes
    function onAuthStateChanged(result) {
      setUser(result)
      console.log(result);
      if (initializing) setInitializing(false)
    }
  
    useEffect(() => {
      const authSubscriber = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(onAuthStateChanged)
  console.log("getting here...")
      // unsubscribe on unmount
      return authSubscriber
    }, [])
  
    if (initializing) {
      return null
    }
  console.log('Hello World')
  console.log(user)
    return !user ? (
      <AuthContext.Provider value={user}>
        <SignInStack />
      </AuthContext.Provider>
    ) : (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={user}>
      <TestScreen/>
      </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
  }
```

TestScreen.js

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';

import { useContext } from 'react'
import { AuthContext } from './../navigation/authnavigator.js'

export default function TestScreen() {
    console.log(useContext(AuthContext))
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Likes You</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: What if you weren't placing the react hook in a console log?

Comment: I see u haven't imported createContext ??

Comment: If I assign the useContext(AuthContext) to a local variable and then log it, it still returns null.

Comment: I didn't import it in TestScreen.js, but I only need to use it, not create it in that file.

Comment: Yeah, I'm 99% sure.

    `<AuthContext.Provider value={user}>
      <TestScreen/>
      </AuthContext.Provider>`

in AuthNavigator.js

Comment: Initial value for `user` is `null`, is this the value you're seeing in the context `TestScreen`? After logging in does the firebase auth pick that up and call the `onAuthStateChanged` callback and update state?

Comment: Yes, I am seeing null in the context when I call useContext(AuthContext) in TestScreen. onAuthStateChanged callback is being called and updating the value of user. Logging verified this and also right before the user is assigned to AuthProvider, it is not null. 

I did notice that when createContext is called with no arguments instead of providing null as the argument, the value of useContext in TestScreen is undefined instead of null. I have some hunches and I'll keep testing...

Comment: I think I figured out the problem. AuthNavigator is being called twice. A console log at the beginning of the function AuthNavigator appears twice when it should be called only once. The first time around, onAuthStateChanged is being called and user is being set, but the second time around, onAuthStateChanged is not being called and so the default null value is being kept.

Comment: That being said, I'm not absolutely sure this is the problem and I'm not sure what the solution is but it's a start.

Comment: Moving the createContext call to a separate file then importing it into authnavigator fixed the problem. Don't understand why, but it worked.

Answer (score -1):

```
    return !user ? (
      <AuthContext.Provider value={user}>
        <SignInStack />
      </AuthContext.Provider>
    ) : (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={user}>
      <TestScreen/>
      </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
  }
```

This part seems problematic to me because you are create two separate `AuthContext.Provider`s.

You should do something like

```
    return
      <AuthContext.Provider value={user}>
        { !user? <SignInStack />:
      <TestScreen/>}
      </AuthContext.Provider>
```

instead. Or you might want to rework some basic login strategie from you own code.

Answer (score -4):

It appears that you are not calling `useContext` from the React `namespace`.

Update your code to this -

```
React.useContext(AuthContext)
```

Instead of this -

```
useContext(AuthContext)
```

For good measure, please change this as well.

```
export const AuthContext = React.createContext(null)
```